# How to use different tool chains

Tags: cmake, cross-platform

In a project where some targets are to be build and run on the build platform and other targets are to be build for a cross platform; what options do we have, when using cmake?

Currently I use `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` to define tool chain, build type and platform (for example `-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=arm_debug`). In one place in the build, I switch tools (compilers, linke etc.), command line flags, libraries etc. according to the value of CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE. For every build type, I create a build directory.

This approach has it's drawbacks: multiple build directories and no easy way to depend one target from one build type on a target in an other build type (some kind of precompiler needed on the build platform by the build for the cross platform for example).

As currently every build targets has a single tool chain to be used I would love to associate a target with a target platform / tools set. This implies that some libraries have to be build for more than one target platform with different tool sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '*one build type and platform per CMake run*' limitation is fundamental and I would strongly advise against trying to work around it.

The proper solution here seems to me to split the build into several stages. In particular, for the scenario where a target from one build type depends on a target from another build type, you should not try to have those two targets in the same CMake project. Proper modularization is key here. Effective use of CMake's `include` command can help to avoid code duplication in the build scripts.

The big drawback of this approach is that the build process becomes more complex, as you now have several interdependent CMake projects that need to be built in a certain order with specific configurations. Although you already seem to be way beyond the point where you can build your whole system with a single command anyway. CMake can help manage this complexity with tools like [`ExternalProject`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/ExternalProject.html), that allows you to build a CMake project from within another. Depending on your particular setup, a non-CMake layer written in your favorite scripting language might also be a viable alternative for ensuring that the different subprojects get built in the correct order.

The sad truth is though that complex build setups are *hard* to manage. CMake does a great job at providing a number of tools for tackling this complexity but it cannot magically make the problem easier. Most of the limitations that CMake imposes on its user are there for a reason, namely that things would be *even harder* if you tried to work without them.